# How to split and concatenate the string in xslt

Tags: java, xslt, xpath, mapping

I am trying to split the string when character is in uppercase n later concatenate with space. For example:--

Given:--

```
<test>UnitOfMeasure</test>
```

Desired o/p:--

```
<final>Unit Of Measure</final>
```

what function/algorithm  I should write to achieve the above requirement(no idea should I use string-split or tokenize() here). Thanks in advance

```
<final>
<Xsl:value-of select= "concat(?)"/>
</final>
```

Comment: Which version of XPath or XSLT? XPath 3.1 has an `analyze-string` function `analyze-string('UnitOfMeasure', '(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)')//fn:group => string-join(' ')`

Comment: @Martin im using 2.0.. will it work?

Comment: Not quite as the `analyze-string` function is not part of XSLT/XPath 2.0 but you can use the same regular expression with the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 and later you can `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
  <xsl:param name="pattern" as="xs:string">(\p{Lu}\p{Ll}*)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="test">
      <final>
          <xsl:value-of separator=" ">
              <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$pattern}">
                  <xsl:matching-substring>
                      <xsl:sequence select="."/>
                  </xsl:matching-substring>
              </xsl:analyze-string>
          </xsl:value-of>
      </final>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I checked but its not working https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGP/1

Comment: Well if you pretend you can run XSLT 2 code with Microsoft's XslCompiledTransform you have selected in the fiddle them I am afraid you are mistaken. The code is XSLT 2 code to be run with Saxon 8.9 or later, XmlPrime, Raptor but certainly not with any XSLT 1 processor. In https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBGP/2 you can see that it works using Saxon 9.8 (where it could be easier done with the `analyze-string` function as 9.8 support XSLT 3.0).

Comment: sorry it was my bad..thanks a lot it worked